Issues with file system level backup and recovery operations on GridDB Node
I am trying to restore backup data to a GridDB node but kept encountering the status NG displayed for one of the backup files which happens to be a file I direly need.
To troubleshoot the issue, I took the following steps:
I ensured that no node had been started and confirmed that the cluster definition file matched the other nodes in the cluster that the joining node is part of.
I also checked the backup name used in the recovery and verified the backup status to select one that has been correctly backed up.
I ensured that there were no leftover data files, checkpoint log files, or transaction log files in the database file directories (/var/lib/gridstore/data and /var/lib/gridstore/txnlog by default) of the node.
I executed the restore command on the machine starting the node and then started the node.
Next, I used the command below to check the backup data:
gs_backuplist -u admin/admin

Here is the list of backup displayed
BackupName   Status  StartTime                 EndTime
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
*201912           --  2019-12-01T05:20:00+09:00 2019-12-01T06:10:55+09:00
*201911           --  2019-11-01T05:20:00+09:00 2019-11-01T06:10:55+09:00
  :
 20191025NO2      OK  2019-10-25T06:37:10+09:00 2019-10-25T06:38:20+09:00
 20191025         NG  2019-10-25T02:13:34+09:00 -
 20191018         OK  2019-10-18T02:10:00+09:00 2019-10-18T02:12:15+09:00

gs_backuplist -u admin/admin 201912

BackupName : 201912

BackupData            Status StartTime                 EndTime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
201912_lv0                OK 2019-12-01T05:20:00+09:00 2019-12-01T06:10:55+09:00
201912_lv1_000_001        OK 2019-12-02T05:20:00+09:00 2019-12-02T05:20:52+09:00
201912_lv1_000_002        OK 2019-12-03T05:20:00+09:00 2019-12-03T05:20:25+09:00
201912_lv1_000_003        OK 2019-12-04T05:20:00+09:00 2019-12-04T05:20:33+09:00
201912_lv1_000_004        OK 2019-12-05T05:20:00+09:00 2019-12-05T05:21:25+09:00
201912_lv1_000_005        OK 2019-12-06T05:20:00+09:00 2019-12-06T05:21:05+09:00
201912_lv1_001_000        OK 2019-12-07T05:20:00+09:00 2019-12-07T05:22:11+09:00
201912_lv1_001_001        OK 2019-12-08T05:20:00+09:00 2019-12-08T05:20:55+09:00


However, I kept encountering the status NG displayed for the 20191025 backup file, and I really need this file restored. Kindly advise on how I can go around this issue.
I'm currently stuck and need assistance restoring this backup data to my GridDB node. Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

If the status displayed is NG, the backup file may be damaged and so restoration is not possible.
Check the data among the 201912 backup data used in the recovery. Differential/incremental backup data used for recovery can be checked in the --test option of gs_restore. In the --test option, only data used for recovery is displayed and restoration of data will not be carried out. Use this in the preliminary checks.
When a specific partition fails, there is a need to check where the latest data of the partition is being maintained.
Use the gs_backuplist command on all the nodes constituting the cluster, and specify the ID of the partition for which you wish to check the --partitionId option for execution. Use the node backup that contains the largest LSN number for recovery. Use the node backup that contains the largest LSN number for recovery.
